# Extend and override existing style with SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using sass bootstrap 3. I'd like to make my buttons use different font than rest of my body. But buttons inherit their font from body.

- I'd like to use the default button styles of Bootstrap, not create new ones
- I'd like to leave the bootstrap `.scss` files intact

I currently have my own `main.scss` which overrides colors etc. and then imports the bootstrap scss. Like this:

```
$border-radius-small:            0px;

@import 'sass-bootstrap/lib/bootstrap';
```

Now, currently I have after the import something like:

```
.demibold {
  font-family: 'The Message DemiBold';
}
```

But then I have to have my buttons like this:

```
<button id="loginButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg demibold">
```

Can I add something to my `main.scss` to change the definition of for example `btn` so I don't need to add `demibold` style to each button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the sass @extend keyword.

```
.btn {
  @extend .demibold;
}
```

This technique is used extensively in the following pattern:
https://coderwall.com/p/wixovg

I tend to use it myself sometimes, but don't go wild with it, using @extend with heavily nested sass files can lead to insanly long css selectors.

edit: If you are going to extend a class declared in another sass file, be sure to import that file into your document.

Comment: Do you know of a better way to override normal bootstrap than extending it like this?